# reading from serial port

Tags: java, serial-port, communication

to read from serial port do i need to install some package the get support in netbeans?
which packages do i need to import at the start of program?

the statement:

import javax.comm.*;
results in error saying package does not exist...what to do

Answer (score 4):

You can use **javax.comm** package.

You can download it in [here](http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=43208d3d).

You can check an example in [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ReadfromaSerialportnotifyingwhendataarrives.htm)

Comment: are there some simple examples available...to start with!

Comment: what to  download from http://www.sun.com/download/products.xml?id=43208d3d
i have netbeans 5.5.1 running with me

Comment: from there u need to download the javax.comm package. and it doesent matter which IDE(netbeans, eclipse or nothing) u are using, the package will behave the same :)